# Join two dimension tables that don't have a shared key column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Employee info (one row per employee) table and a Calendar table (one row per day).

I want a results table that has one row per day for each employee.

employee table

| EmpID | EmpName |
| --- | --- |
| 0001 | Jill |
| 0002 | Bill |
| 0003 | Steve |

calendar table

| Date | Month |
| --- | --- |
| 01/01/2022 | January |
| 01/02/2022 | January |
| 01/03/2022 | January |

result table

| Date | EmpName |
| --- | --- |
| 01/01/2022 | Jill |
| 01/01/2022 | Bill |
| 01/01/2022 | Steve |
| 01/02/2022 | Jill |
| 01/02/2022 | Bill |
| 01/02/2022 | Steve |
| 01/03/2022 | Jill |
| 01/03/2022 | Bill |
| 01/03/2022 | Steve |

Comment: `CROSS JOIN`..?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A cross join is what you want:

```
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE_TABLE
CROSS JOIN CALENDAR_TABLE;
```

A cross join literally just multiplies the number of rows in the first table with the number of rows in the second table.

Comment: Spectacular. I've been working with SQL professionally for close to two years now and I hadn't heard of Cross Joins. Thank you!